# Split a string with a delimiter and leave the first column

Tags: bash, sed, split

I have the following structure:

```
column1,column2
value1,string1;string2;string3;string4
value2,string11;string22
```

I would like to modify that structure and create a new file with the following format:

```
column1,column2
value1,string1
value1,string2
value1,string3
value1,string4
value2,string11
value2,string22
```

Comment: You almost certainly want to use awk and not sed for this.

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner should help:

```
awk -F"[;,]" 'NR==1{print;next}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1","$i}' file
```

Comment: Above didn't worked for me (for some reason...). Instead this worked ok : `echo "value1,string1;string2;string3;string4" |awk -F"[;,]" 'NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1","$i}'`. I just removed the `{print;next}` part of your one-liner.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou pls test with the given example in your question. you pass single line to my one-liner, and it will just print it out without doing any processing. same as your `column1,column2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed solution, if only to show how much easier it is in awk (and because writing sed commands is fun):

```
$ sed '1b;:a;s/^\([^,]*\),\([^;]*\);/\1,\2\n\1,/;ta' infile
column1,column2
value1,string1
value1,string2
value1,string3
value1,string4
value2,string11
value2,string22
```

This is based on the observation that in each line (after the first one), the `;` has to be replaced by a newline, the first word and a comma.

Readable with comments:

```
1b                                   # On first line: jump to end and print
:loop                                # Label to jump to
s/^\([^,]*\),\([^;]*\);/\1,\2\n\1,/  # Substitute one ";" as described above
t loop                               # If the pattern was modified, jump to "loop"
```

The capture groups in the substitution command are "characters other than `,` from the beginning of the line" (first group) and "characters other than `;` between `,` and the first `;`", so while looping over the first line to be changed, the first capture group is always `value1`, and the second one is, in each iteration, `string1`, `string2` and so on.

BSD sed, as found for example in MacOS, complains about branching labels in one-liners. In that case, the command would have to be broken up like this:

```
sed -e '1b;:a' -e's/^\([^,]*\),\([^;]*\);/\1,\2\n\1,/;ta' infile
```